# Ignoring/accepting forward slashes with htaccess and mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need a little help on this one.

I'm in the process of making a php page that collects a query string, tests it against a database for matches, and then redirects the user to a different section of the site.

The is how it works currently (without htaccess/mod_rewrite):

1. User visits: domain.com/redirect/index.php?slug=Test_1
2. The php page sanitizes and looks up 'Test_1' in the database and retrieves a destination URL to redirect the user to. (e.g. domain.com/New_Test_1)
3. The php page then 301 redirects accordingly.

This part is working fine. However, due to some variables outside of my control, I need to interpret the original URL (using htaccess/mod_rewrite), like this:

- domain.com/redirect/index.php/Test_1

Which still acts the same as:

- domain.com/redirect/index.php?slug=Test_1

(note: yes, the index.php needs to stay in the url.)

I have this working with the following in my htaccess, but I know it could be better:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/redirect/index.php?slug=$2 [PT,L,QSA]
```

**Part I need help with...**

Some of the old url slugs had forward slashes in them, like this:

- domain.com/redirect/index.php?slug=How_to_Code/Program

Without htaccess, the above still works, but fails with the pretty(ier) url:

- domain.com/redirect/index.php/How_to_Code/Program

With my current htaccess, it only captures the 'How_to_Code' part, but ignores everything after it.

So my question is this: how can I restructure my htaccess to grab everything after domain.com/redirect/index.php/(.*)$, including forward slashes?

*Edit: this .htaccess is going inside the /redirect directory*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do this

```
RewriteRule ^redirect/index.php/([a-zA-Z0-9/_]+)$ redirect/index.php?slug=$1
```

That will accept forward slashes and underscores. To add anymore allowed characters just add them inside the [] square brackets. Certain characters may need to be escaped so just Google that.

Comment: Thanks David, this .htaccess is going inside the /redirect directory. I've tried your rule, but the capture ($1) isn't returning any results. Any ideas?

Comment: If it's in your redirect directory then just put
`RewriteRule ^index.php/([a-zA-Z0-9/_]+)$ index.php?slug=$1`

That will redirect to the index.php file in the redirect folder while keeping the url like www.yoursite.com/redirect/index.php/Some_value

Comment: You got me exactly where I needed to go. I ended up using

`RewriteRule ^index.php/(.+)$ index.php?slug=$1 [PT,L,QSA]`

Only because there's a lot of character possibilities (beyond just the forward slash). Are there any security concerns doing it this way?

Comment: There is always more security concerns when you allow more characters. It is always better to know what characters you will be expecting and stick to those, but if the range of characters is very high then just secure the variable $_GET['slug'] with the PHP addslashes() function or the mysql_real_escape_string() function before you do your databae query or better yet use prepared statements to make it more secure. Also if you know the $slug value will never exceed 50 characters then check its length before the database query. This will prevent hackers using their own long malicious sql queries